# How to do Client Certificate Authentication using NSURLSession with background session configuration?

Tags: ios, nsurlsession, background-fetch, nsurlsessionconfiguration, nsurlcredential

My application backend requires Client Certificate authentication. If I configure NSURLSession with default configuration, didReceiveChallenge delegate gets called where I am providing valid client certificate. It successfully completes the task. 
But in case of background session configuration didReceiveChallenge gets called and I am providing same certificate but it is not working.

Comment: Assuming you're referring to a background session receiving a challenge while your app is still active, there shouldn't be any difference; `URLSession:didReceiveChallenge:completionHandler: ` should be invoked regardless of whether the session is default or background configured. Update your question with the simplest code that reproduces the problem.

Comment: Judging by a comment by Quinn about WKWebView, I suspect that this is a dup of rdar://22659960, in which case it is a known bug, but I don't have Radar visibility these days, so I can't say for sure.  Either way, file a bug.